# Can I call a ruby function/method defined in a .rb file from C dll used in that file?

Tags: c, ruby, dll

I have a .rb file (Sketchup plugin), which uses C dll written by me. I'm getting callbacks into my dll from another source and I need to somehow pass those callbacks (strings) into ruby so I could parse them and use them further in the plugin.
Is there an elegant way to do so?

Passing function reference from ruby to the dll so I could call a ruby function everytime a callback comes and via this function get the callback back to the plugin seems impossible since ruby doesn't really work with references/pointers (from what I've researched).

It's all done on Windows, using ruby 2.4.0.

Comment: It's definitely possible, but way beyond my expertise. Check out [this thread](http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=180&t=39072) on the topic, as well as the guide for [extending ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html). They both have helpful information on accessing ruby from C.

Comment: I think you're looking at this in a suboptimal manner. There should be no need to parse Strings and map them to functions when you could pass them as Proc objects and simply call `call` (using `rb_funcall2` in C). You can look at the [`iodine` repo](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine), where I authored [a small helper](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/bb470b223bd8a48aab52b3610ba6997adc2c7570/ext/iodine/rb-call.c) to deal with `rb_funcall2` in a multi-threaded environment that enters and leaves the GVL's protection (you probably don't need it, but it's decent example code).